# Bridged network setup with gateway not in netmask

Tags: linux, networking, routing, netmask

i'm currently stuck at setting up the bridged networking on a dedicated server to allow the KVM-guests to use ips from an extra subnet.
As far as i know, the address, broadcast and gateway must always be in range of the netmask.

My original network setup (/etc/network/interfaces) looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address      1.2.3.163
  broadcast    1.2.3.191
  netmask      255.255.255.224
  gateway      1.2.3.161
```

So, to allow using the device as a bridge, i changed the file like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address      1.2.3.163
  broadcast    1.2.3.191
  netmask      255.255.255.224
  gateway      1.2.3.161
  bridge-ports eth0
```

Result: Networking still available. However this is the information i got from the provider:

```
subnet: 9.8.7.200/29
addresses: 9.8.7.(200-207)
netmask: 255.255.255.248
gateway: 1.2.3.163
broadcast: 9.8.7.207
```

So the gateway as actually my main ip. However it does not exists in the current network. I've added a second bridge to my interfaces file:

```
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
  address      9.8.7.200
  broadcast    9.8.7.207
  netmask      255.255.255.248
  gateway      1.2.3.163
  bridge-ports eth0
```

The result is: i can ping 9.8.7.200, however when trying to ping via br1, no host can be resolved. The output of "route -n" is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         1.2.3.161       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
9.8.7.200       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 br1
1.2.3.160       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 br0
```

I'm looking forward thankfully for any assistance with this problem.

Comment: You will need to setup your KVM host as a router for this to work.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/400395/linux-as-a-gateway-no-nat for more information.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The info from the provider is wrong. The gateway for 9.8.7.200/29 cannot be 1.2.3.163.

Comment: Is that subnet routed to your dedicated server? I guess the provider just tells you this. It simple does not provide a router for that network, that has to be your machine.
You might use the dedicated servers default gateway, but have to set an appropriate route on your VMs. (eg 1.2.3.161/32 -> eth0)
That /might/ work, if your provider is not too picky about what ARP request it answers. And you'll have to check whether returning packets get to your dedic/vms....
But finally: Use a /routed/ setup.

Answer (score 0):

The Gateway is wrong.
It must reside within the same subnet as your IP is. otherwhise it wont work.

```
IP:        9.8.7.200
Netmask:   255.255.255.248 (/29)
Network:   9.8.7.200
Broadcast: 9.8.7.207   
First IP:  9.8.7.201
Last IP:   9.8.7.206
```

I configured my bridge the folowing way:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 1.2.3.0
        broadcast 1.2.3.255
        gateway 1.2.3.1

#(as is work with openvpn interfaces)

auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
  pre-up openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
  post-down openvpn --rmtun --dev tap0

auto tap1
    iface tap1 inet manual
      pre-up openvpn --mktun --dev tap1
      post-down openvpn --rmtun --dev tap1

   auto br0
  iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports tap0 tap1 
    address 10.20.30.40
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.20.30.101
    up route add -net 172.16.25.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.20.30.100
    down route del -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.20.30.101
    down route del -net 172.16.25.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.20.30.100
```

All the OpenVPN Client Networks ar routet, and can connect to the internet if they use the servres OpenVPN IP as gateway. (redirect gateway option)

Comment: I talked to the provider, one of the support guys told me how it goes in a right way.

The new subnet is routed to the main address form the server, thats why there is no need for a gateway to use the additional IP-addresses.

example:
``Network:  88.1.1.80
Broadcast: 88.1.1.87
Usable addresses: 88.1.1.81 – 88.1.1.86
``

Comment: So they gave You TWO Subnets where one is accessible through the other? Network A: 1.2.3.0/29 Network B: 2.3.4.0/29, and they set up a route like this route add -net 2.3.4.0/29 gw 1.2.3.1 ? Am i understanding this right?

Comment: Exactly, my range is between network and broadcast. EDIT: I mean it is some time ago, I just remember that what you can read on top.